# Istanbul coverage + mocha + teamcity reporter

Tags: javascript, teamcity, mocha.js, istanbul

I would like to run tests with istanbul coverage on TeamCity and report test results back to the Tests tab.
I run the following command:

```
node --harmony C:\...\node_modules\istanbul\lib\cli.js cover C:\...\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter  --require C:\...\tests_setup.js C:\...\test\**\*Test.js && node --harmony C:\...\istanbul\lib\cli.js report teamcity
```

I see coverage results in my tab Code Coverage, but tests are not shown in the tab Tests. I have the following error in my logs:

```
 >> Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: mocha-teamcity-reporter
```

What could be wrong ? Is it possible to run istanbul coverage for mocha tests and report test results back to the teamcity for the tab Tests ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are not being passed to mocha.

https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul#the-cover-command

You need to add `--` to pass parameters to the covered command

```
node --harmony C:\...\node_modules\istanbul\lib\cli.js cover \
    C:\...\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha -- \
    --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter \
    --require C:\...\tests_setup.js C:\...\test\**\*Test.js
```

or without global paths

```
istanbul cover mocha -- --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter --require tests_setup.js test/**/*Test.js
```